# What are best practices of implementing user login session in android application?

Tags: android, authentication

The requirement is implementing login feature for an android application which has an expire time duration. For instance , the expire time (session time) is 10 minutes, The app should redirects the user to login screen to refresh the login information and have a new token from the server.

Here , the problem is there is no session management in android like web application frameworks. so that what are the best recommended ways to implement the required feature on android.

Answer (score 3):

What we do

1) When user login to app , get access token from server and save it in shared preferences in encrypted format.

2) Send this access token in every request

3) If access token is expired then we get error response in request

4) When ever we get error response , we clear shared prefs and we redirect user to login screen .